# Obj-C creating a battle scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This has been a problem for me for almost a week so I figured i'd post it here for help. I'm still learning Obj-C so bear with me. Ill post my code then explain what I'm trying to do:

```
- (void) resetStats {
self.heroHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.heroAtkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.heroDefLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.heroSpdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.enemyAtkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.enemyDefLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
self.enemySpdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
}

- (void) setHeroStats {
self.heroHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", heroHp];
self.heroAtkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", heroAtk];
self.heroDefLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", heroDef];
self.heroSpdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", heroSpd];
}

- (void) enemy1 {
enemyHp = 100;
enemyAtk = 1;
enemyDef = 0;
enemySpd = 5;
int enemy1Hp;
enemy1Hp = enemyHp;
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemyHp];
self.enemyAtkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemyAtk];
self.enemyDefLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemyDef];
self.enemySpdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemySpd];
enemy1Alive = YES;
if (enemyHp <= 0) {
    NSLog(@"the enemy is dead");
    [self resetStats];
}
}


- (IBAction)fight:(id)sender {
if (battleActive == NO) {
    self.fightOutlet.hidden = YES;
    [self setHeroStats];
    [self enemy1];
    battleActive = YES;
    if (heroHp <= 0) {
        battleActive = NO;
        self.fightOutlet.hidden = NO;
        [self resetStats];
    }
} else if (battleActive == YES)
    useless = 0;

}
```

So, to explain this mess. What I am trying to do is create a very simple "battle" scene in which the hero will fight an enemy with 4 different stats. When I press the "battle button" (the fight action) the labels on the VC (don't have enough rep to post an image) update to show the stats of the Hero and enemy that is spawned Hp, Atk, Def, Spd.

What I'm trying to do is to make it so that if the enemy's health is 0 or less then enemy1 will stop running and enemy2 will be called which will change all of the enemy stats accordingly (enemy2 hasn't been made yet because I'm stuck on this next part) what I can't figure out what to do is make it so that the enemy will take damage (for learning reasons and keeping it simple I've made a button that will take away 100 hp).

Example because I'm confused just writing this:

The user presses the "battle" button

The stat labels get updated accordingly

The user presses a button that will deal damage to the enemy equal to the hero's attack minus the enemy's defense.

When the enemy's health is <= 0 then the enemy stats will be updated to the stats of enemy2

This cycle will continue until the hero's health is <=0 (after the hero attacks the enemy will attack back unless it was killed by said attack) when the hero dies all stats will be reset to "0" and it can be done again.

Like I said, I'm new and have been stuck on this for awhile so i apologize if this is really simple to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you should probably make your question more specific, for example: the monster didn't disappear, the game doesn't end etc.
I didn't really read your code, but I think you should learn how to use classes first instead of only functions. 
**Btw, your code is not working as you only change the text of the label but not the actual VALUE of those instances **
Also, the function enemy will never work as you reset the enemy's hp every time you call the function.
Create a class for monster and another class for hero , at least your code can be less messy and readable.